# is it ok to power a 90v dc motor with 170v dc and pwm?

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, bridge-rectifier

I need to control a 90v dc motor, the thing is that I dont have a way to get a 90v suply so I just rectified the ac voltage and got 170 volts, without any load and filter caps, as far as I know this voltage will drop once there is a load but it is stil high, is it ok to use pwm at this voltage to power the motor, obviously with about 60% duty cycle.

Comment: Stop what you're doing before you hurt yourself.

Comment: so it is not ok?

Comment: use a regular 110v light bulb (maybe 60W) as a test load and see what the output voltage is when loaded. the worst that will happen is a burned-out lightbulb (try 2 in series if necessary) ... use 100W for a heavier load

Comment: You might get away with it when using a heater, although that still would be dangerous. Don't do this with a motor. Many things can go wrong: 1.9 times the voltage could be 3.6 times the power; sparks could damage the motor; current spikes could damage the motor; inductive flyback currents could be out of control; and so on.

Comment: any suggestions to reduce the voltage apart from using a transformer?

Comment: In principal you can use PWM to reduce the effective voltage of a motor. But playing with rectified line voltage is dangerous to your person. Also, there is a chance that the insulation of the winding in the motor may brake down during the PWM high time. Also there is a chance that parts of the motor may get energized at dangerous voltages and people may get shocked touching the outside of the motor.

Comment: All you need is a buck converter.

Comment: Just buy a 90 VDC DC Drive.  You can get some for under $50 US.  Still not line isolated, but it will provide motor protection, variable speed, ramps etc.

Comment: As @MattYoung has pointed out, stop now before doing anything else! The fact you have "just rectified the ac voltage" tells a story... Read about power supplies, then get a transformer and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not very OK.  During any software glitch, you might be running your motor at 125% of rated RPM.  (DC motor speed is proportional to drive voltage.)   Instead, use a single 400V power diode rather than a bridge rectifier.  That should run your motor at roughly 65% of full speed, at most.

90VDC motors are intended for use with motor speed controls:  a specialized triac dimmer followed by a full-wave bridge rectifier.  ($40 to $100 on eBay!)   The little [KB Inc. or Dart motor controllers](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=dart%20125%20speed&_sop=15&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=dart%20125%20motor%20speed&_sacat=0) typically adjust from 0% to 75% of full AC output.

Your 170V reading is probably wrong; you're seeing the peak volts rather than unfiltered true-RMS average.

To reduce the motor voltage, you could try using a standard incandescent lighting dimmer, plus a bridge rectifier.  Choose a dimmer-wattage rating appropriate to the horsepower rating for your motor.

If you want to play with opto-isolated, voltage-signal AC controllers, VELLEMAN KITS has a $30 unit, a lighting dimmer pcb kit with 0V-10Vdc control input.